# LDAP search base DN not working

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, distinguishedname, ou

I'm trying to perform an LDAP search into many different OUs that are located at the root of the directory.

Context initialization:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "somePassword");
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "MYDOMAIN\\\\myUsername");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://myLdapServer:389");
searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

So for searching an user I call

```
ctx.search("OU=OrgUnitOne,DC=mysite,DC=com", "(sAMAccountName=someUserName)", searchControls)
```

or

```
ctx.search("OU=OrgUnitTwo,DC=mysite,DC=com", "(sAMAccountName=someUserName)", searchControls)
```

and either works fine. But since I want to search into all of OUs in the root of DA, I have to use another baseDN for the search, which I've failed to find. I've tried the following but none seems to work...

**Without OU:**

```
ctx.search("DC=mysite,DC=com", "(sAMAccountName=someUserName)", searchControls)
//output:
//javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name 'DC=mysite,DC=com'
```

**Empty `searchBase` string:**

```
ctx.search("", "(sAMAccountName=someUserName)", searchControls)
//output:
//javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E5, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:'']; remaining name ''
```

**Desperate wildcard ***

```
ctx.search("OU=\*,DC=mysite,DC=com", "(sAMAccountName=someUserName)", searchControls)
//output:
//javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:'DC=mysite,DC=com']; remaining name 'OU=*,DC=mysite,DC=com'
```

**Desperate wildcard %**

```
ctx.search("OU=%,DC=mysite,DC=com", "(sAMAccountName=someUserName)", searchControls)
//output:
//javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:'DC=mysite,DC=com']; remaining name 'OU=%,DC=mysite,DC=com'
```

**Desperate OR operator |**

```
ctx.search("OU=OrgUnitOne|OrgUnitTwo,DC=mysite,DC=com", "(sAMAccountName=someUserName)", searchControls)
//output:
//javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:'DC=mysite,DC=com'];
```

remaining name `'OU=OrgUnitOne|OrgUnitTwo,DC=mysite,DC=com'`

Is there a way to achieve this search over all the root OUs?

Comment: Have you considered looking up the documentation for `javax.naming.PartialResultException`? instead of floundering around with wild guesses?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://ldapHost");
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com");
ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
// Create the search controls         
SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
// Specify the attributes to return
String returnedAtts[]={"sn","givenName", "samAccountName"};
searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
// Specify the search scope
searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
// specify the LDAP search filter
String searchFilter = "(&(samAccountName=userName))";
// Specify the Base for the search
String searchBase = "dc=domain,dc=com";
// initialize counter to total the results
int totalResults = 0;
// Search for objects using the filter
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
// Loop through the search results
while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
    SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
    totalResults++;
    System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName());
    Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
    System.out.println(">>>>>>" + attrs.get("samAccountName"));       
}
System.out.println("Total results: " + totalResults);
ldapContext.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a search request using the desired base object, a search scope of `sub`, a filter that restricts the entries returned to just the entries desired, and a list of requested attributes. Using the UnboundID LDAP SDK:

```
SearchRequest req = new SearchRequest("dc=mysite,dc=com",
       SearchScope.SUB,"samAccountName=someUserName","1.1");
SearchResult searchResult = ldapConnection.search(req);
```

This search will return all of the entries (`1.1` means return no attributes, replace this with the list of attributes desired) in which the samAccounName attribute contains the value "someUserName" (matching of the values is performed using matching rules) *if the server permits*. In some cases, the server administrators may not permit this search because it traverses the entire directory server database. Also, the connection's authorization state must permit the examination of the `samAccountName`. Note that a search can be successful (result code SUCCESS, integer 0) but no entries returned.

- The is no "or" operator for distinguished names.
- There is no "wildcard" operator in distinguished names

Comment: Thank you very much Terry, but I might not be able to use UnboundID SDK, so I wonder if the base object "dc=mysite,dc=com" can be elsehow specified using javax.naming API.

Comment: It appears that your client received a continuation reference when you did a search starting from `dc=mysite,dc=com`. You might need to follow referrals.

Comment: @Terry Gardner The link you have provided is broken. Please update it with working one.